# Time zone detection by city/country name php 8.1 / Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, php-8.1, symfony5.4

What are the ways to get the time zone given the city code in php8.1 with Symfony 5.4?

Comment: Use some API such as https://api-ninjas.com/api/timezone or http://geodb-cities-api.wirefreethought.com/docs/api/get-time-zones . There are others too, you can google it easily

Comment: Location detection is unreliable at best. Just ask the user or otherwise let them configure it.

Comment: Timezones are notoriously complex because they're changing frequently globally. For this reason, it would be best to use a third-party API, instead of attempting to do it alone. Then use their SDK to grab the API data and go from there.

Comment: Closing as a recommendation question - there's no way to write a _program_ that knows what a "city code" means and what time zone it maps to, without a source of _data_ about that list of cities. That's well beyond the scope of the timezone database that ships with PHP / your system, so as others say, you're probably going to need to integrate an API.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Intl componenet check the documentation here [IntlComponenet](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html#timezones)

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Timezones;

\Locale::setDefault('en');

 $timezones = Timezones::getNames();

 $timezone = Timezones::getName('Africa/Nairobi');
 // => 'East Africa Time (Nairobi)'
```

Note: I took this code from documentation

Comment: Ty, but I want get time zone by city code. 
Example like get_time_zone_by_country_and_region('US','DE')